# ObservableCollection add new item not showing on datagrid unless refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a ObservableCollection list, and set binding to a datagrid in WPF.  However, when I add an item to the list the datagrid won't update unless I refresh the itemssource.

Here is my code.

```
ObservableCollection<FLEET_SERIES> listAC = new ObservableCollection<FLEET_SERIES>();
///Add some items to listAC
```

Here is where I add an additional item to the list

```
private void AcTypeDtg_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    listAC.Add(new FLEET_SERIES()
    {
        PART_NUMBER= "SOMESTRING"
        FLEET = null,
        SERIES=null        
    });
}
```

Here is my xaml code for the datagrid

```
<DataGrid 
    Name="AcTypeDtg" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding listAC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"  
    CanUserAddRows="False" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="AcTypeDtg_MouseRightButtonDown"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            x:Name="fleetCol" 
            Header="Fleet" 
            Width = "100*" 
            IsReadOnly="True" 
            Binding="{Binding FLEET, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
            >
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Series" 
            x:Name="SeriesColumn" 
            Width = "100*" 
            IsReadOnly="True" 
            Binding="{Binding SERIES, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
            >
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is my class FLEET_SERIES

```
public partial class FLEET_SERIES:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region Members
    private string _pART_NUMBER;
    private string _fLEET;
    private string _sERIES;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string PART_NUMBER { get { return _pART_NUMBER; } set { _pART_NUMBER = value; OnPropertyChanged("PART_NUMBER"); } }
    public string FLEET { get { return _fLEET; } set { _fLEET = value; OnPropertyChanged("FLEET"); } }
    public string SERIES { get { return _sERIES; } set { _sERIES = value; OnPropertyChanged("SERIES"); } }
    #endregion

    // INotifyPropertyChanged interface       
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

So when I add an additional item. the datagrid won't update.  However, if I set the itemssource to null and then set to listAC. it would show the added additional item.  Any idea why?

I thought ObservableCollection has implemented collectionchange.  Do I need a separate handler to handle the collectionchange?....Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need all this stuff: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True`. Setting random properties in random places is just a waste of time. Why set properties if you don't know what they mean?

Comment: What is `listAC`? I see a local variable in your code, but you bind it like it's a property. Are you *also* setting `AcTypeDtg.ItemsSource` explicitly somewhere in the code behind? Please share a complete example that fills in the blanks.

Comment: Well, I didn't have those at the first place then searched around,some say put these on but it didn't help....anyway, settings on those are not the cause of the problem....with or without these the problem is the same

Comment: oh, yes, i do have a place set:   AcTypeDtg.ItemsSource = listAC

Comment: So it's not a property. Do you have a viewmodel? You should write a viewmodel, and make that collection a property of the viewmodel. Assign an instance of the viewmodel to the DataContext  of your window. Bind the property in the XAML *do not assign it directly*, then add items to it as needed.

Comment: No. it is not. Sorry I am quite new to WPF, probably lots of mistakes here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169604/discussion-between-optimusprime-and-ed-plunkett).

Comment: Please show all relevant parts of our code including the entire code-behind class.